# why am I getting a response from jquery ajax call as the whole html page and not just the JSON object

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, jsp

I want to get the JSON object to be the only response from my JSP page

I am working on NetBeans, I have already tried to change the resonse.setContentType to text/html and text/plainText in my JSP page,but of no use

this is the ajax call to sendTrain.jsp

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:"sendTrain.jsp",
        data: {
            lat : pos.lat ,
            lng : pos.lng
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    console.log("I did it");
                    alert(data);
                }
    });

});
```

and this  is the sendTrain.jsp page that the ajax calls

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>    
    <%  
        integrateLatLngIntoOneObject integrateObjects=new integrateLatLngIntoOneObject();
        integrateObjects.setLat1(station1LatLng.getLat());
        integrateObjects.setLng1(station1LatLng.getLng());
        integrateObjects.setLat2(station2LatLng.getLat());
        integrateObjects.setLng2(station2LatLng.getLng());

        //parse to JSON format using GSON api
        Gson json=new Gson();
        String jsonResponse= json.toJson(integrateObjects);
        out.print(jsonResponse);
        %>
    </body>
 </html>
```

I expect the response to be only the JSON object , but the actual output is all the html tags with the json object as response.

Comment: It's because you're including HTML in the response page. If you only want JSON in the response, then that's all you should `out.print` to the page

Comment: I did't get you, I did out.print(JsonRespobse) only and not the whole html page,can you please elaborate your point

Comment: You are sending back HTML. Take out all the html from `sendTrain.jsp`, also add a header in code saying the response type is `application/json`.

Comment: Thanks Steve, removing the html tags solved the problem